# Problems getting Django up and running on OSX

Tags: python, django, easy-install, mysql-python

First, I'm following the tutorial on the Django Poll application on their site and have hit a few road blocks.

I've installed Python 2.7 and Django 1.3

Created a new project with

```
django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

I got mysql up and running and entered the credentials in `settings.py`

Then when I try to run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

it puked ... http://pastie.org/2294709

Then when I installed Mysql-python

```
easy_install mysql-python
```

Success! ...

```
Searching for MySQL-python
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.3
Adding MySQL-python 1.2.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
Processing dependencies for MySQL-python
Finished processing dependencies for MySQL-python
```

so I try again

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Still pukes the same message as above

Am I missing Something?

Comment: What do you have for `DATABASES` in settings.py?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.6 or Python 2.7? Look at the output you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jondavidjohn's comment is spot on: you will have no end of confusion with multiple versions of Python on the Mac. There are some things you can do to deal with this.

1. Stick with 2.6
2. Convert to Lion, which has 2.7
3. Add an alias to your shell environment to invoke version 2.7 with $ python. In my bash_profile, I have "alias python='/usr/local/bin/python'"
4. Be sure to set your PYTHONPATH variable to the site packages directory that corresponds to the version of Python that you're using, such as PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages
5. Make sure you know which version of easy_install is operative; many module problems arise from assuming that easy_install will use the same site-packages version for everything. Not true always. Every different Python bin directory has its own version of easy_install (or pip, by preference) which will use the corresponding site packages directory.
6. **Don't** try to run Django under Python 3.x
7. **Don't** try to get rid of the OS version of Python; it will break  your installation because software update sometimes relies on it.
8. Once you're past this hurdle, there are some other parts of getting the sample poll app in Django to run that I had problems with, so I put my experience at https://github.com/technocrat/Writing-your-first-Django-app

Comment: Seems like a hell of a lot of complexity to get to end goal of language simplicity.  Thanks!

Comment: ok, so what I'm seeing is that I should just stick with the OS version, when I type `python` into the command line I get 2.7.2, how do I uninstall it now that I've installed it?

Comment: @Richard: There is no need to change PYTHONPATH nor create an alias.  On OS X 10.6, if you want to use `python2.7` as your primary Python, either just type `python2.7` or, simpler, ensure that the python2.7 framework bin directory comes first on your SHELL path.  If you use the python.org installers for python2.7, by default it will add that to your shell profiles automatically or you can launch `/Applications/Python 2.7/Update\ Shell Profile.command` to do it for you.  Then ensure you install an `easy_install` for the Python 2.7 and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install and use a version of `easy_install` for your Python 2.7.  You are using  the version for the system Python 2.6.  Follow the instructions [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) to install Distribute using `python2.7` to launch python.  Then use `easy_install-2.7` to install `mysql-python`.

Comment: So I guess you can have multiple version of python installed at once? seems like this is going to get very confusing.

Comment: Apple ships OS X with multiple versions of Python installed.  10.6 includes Python 2.6.1 and 2.5.4.  10.7 Lion includes 2.7.1, 2.6.6, and 2.5.4.  It's really not a problem if you understand what comes first on your PATH and you understand that you need a version of easy_install for each Python.